# How to set cookie in detox tests (rn)

Tags: react-native, cookies, mocking, detox, react-native-cookies

I need to test the view of my application based on api response. That's why I need to set up the same cookie as for my app and for api call (eg. like to be the same unauthorised user).

I've tried to implement @react-native-community/cookies, but they needed to be mocked.

Is there a way of doing like that? Any ideas?

Comment: what is the problem with mocking API responses while testing?
I think it's a standard approach to test your application.

Comment: mocking is not suitable in our case

Comment: terms "test" and "mocking" are using together. please tell us why you are persisting in using real data in the test environment.

Comment: my question was about is it possible to set cookie in detox, if u don't know how, I will be still waiting for someone's question.

Comment: I will be still waiting for someone's answer too.